# VirtualHost in Apache delivers wrong page for browser (but not for curl)

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, virtualhost, configuration, apache2

I try to host different websites on the same Apache server (Apache 2.4 running on Ubuntu 16.04) by using different virtual hosts. However, when trying to open `domain-two.tld` the server delivers the webpage of `domain-one.tld`.
Similar behavior is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44737654) and [that](https://askubuntu.com/a/395362) question. According to my config files, the answers of those two questions should be implemented already.

The virtual hosts are defined as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain-one.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain-one.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain_one
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain-two.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain-two.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain_two
</VirtualHost>
```

Both config files are located in `sites-available` and are symlinked into `sites-enabled` by using `a2ensite` leading to the following directory tree:

```
sites-enabled/
|-- domain_one.conf -> ../sites-available/domain_one.conf
`-- domain_two.conf -> ../sites-available/domain_two.conf
```

After the config files have been enabled I restarted apache in order to reload its config files by `systemctl restart apache2`.
In order to test both configuration I added some additional hosts to the `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       domain-one.tld
127.0.0.1       www.domain-one.tld
127.0.0.1       domain-two.tld
127.0.0.1       www.domain-two.tld
# some further IPs down here
```

and accessed both websites locally using curl.

This returns the correct documents as desired. However, accessing both sites via a browser from a remote client Apache delivers `domain_one` only (could not test for `domain-two.tld` due to technical reasons, cache is deactivated in browser).

Where does this strange behavior come from? How could I narrow this down?

---

Update due to @kubanczyk's comment:

- Question: What is returned to remote `curl` requests instead of local `curl` request against `localhost`?
- Answer: Correct page contents.

For [pvz-sphere.de](http://www.pvz-sphere.de) which is `domain_one`:

```
$ curl -v http://www.pvz-sphere.de      # which is domain_one
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.pvz-sphere.de/
*   Trying 217.160.122.225...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.pvz-sphere.de (217.160.122.225) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.pvz-sphere.de
> User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 905
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=15
< Date: Wed, 06 Jun 2018 15:45:32 GMT
< Server: Apache
< 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>SPhERe - Symposium on Pharmaceutical Engineering Research</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="SPhERe, ICTV, TU Braunschweig, PVZ, Zentrum für Pharmaverfahrenstechnik, Institut für Chemische und Thermische Verfahrenstechnik" />
<meta name="description" content="Symposium on Pharmaceutical Engineering Research" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<frameset rows="100%">
<frame src="http://ictv.rz.tu-bs.de/SPhERe/" title="SPhERe - Symposium on Pharmaceutical Engineering Research" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize"/>
<noframes>
<body>
<h1>SPhERe - Symposium on Pharmaceutical Engineering Research</h1>
<p><a href="http://ictv.rz.tu-bs.de/SPhERe/">http://pvz-sphere.de/</a></p>
</body>
</noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host www.pvz-sphere.de left intact
```

For [teresa-projekt.de](http://www.teresa-projekt.de) which is `domain_two`:

```
$ curl -v http://www.teresa-projekt.de    # which is domain_two
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.teresa-projekt.de/
*   Trying 217.160.233.207...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.teresa-projekt.de (217.160.233.207) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.teresa-projekt.de
> User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=15
< Date: Wed, 06 Jun 2018 15:38:17 GMT
< Server: Apache
< 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Teresa-Projekt</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<frameset rows="100%">
<frame src="http://ictv.rz.tu-bs.de" title="Teresa-Projekt" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize"/>
<noframes>
<body>
<h1>Teresa-Projekt</h1>
<p><a href="http://ictv.rz.tu-bs.de">http://teresa-projekt.de/</a></p>
</body>
</noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host www.teresa-projekt.de left intact
```

Comment: I understand how curl accesses `127.0.0.1` but no idea how a remote browser does that. Please edit into the question the output of a remote `curl -v http://x`

Comment: @kubanczyk: Please see added output snippets. Using curl from remote works as desired. Using browser with disabled cache or from different machine does not :-/

Comment: Nah, my browser displays two different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I had a look into the request and response headers as well as to the different log files (after enabling forensic logging), I found out that both the domain redirect (was of type `iframe redirection` instead of `HTTP redirect`) and the DNS entries were faulty. Those faulty DNS entries and the redirect made Apache delivering the default `VirtualHost` since none of the given `ServerNames`or `ServerAlias` matched the requested domains.